# Which problems do injection tokens solve in Angular?

Tags: angular, token, code-injection

I have read countless articles on the machinery of injection tokens. But I have yet to see an example use case that couldn't be done with a seemingly much less involved globally defined value, class, factory, etc.  For example, rather than inject a token defining a function into the app module, I could just define a function globally to be referenced directly by all the components. Are there some concrete examples showing the where injection tokens shine?

I have read numerous articles looking for an example that couldn't be done equal or better using trivial existing language structures.

Comment: I had the same troubles in understanding injection tokens when I started studying Angular. However, now injection tokens (along with DI and IOC) just look like the right way to do things. Global variables have a lot of problems: they rely on "magic words", they pollute the global scope, they may conflict, and so on. Using injection tokens you know that a token is not defined globally, but it's defined only in the scope of an injector. This allows to third party to define tokens on your injector, or have different injectors in your project

Answer (score 2):

Even if Angular is written in TypeScript, which is then transpiled in JavaScript, it doesn't mean that every already existent construct will just work effortless. An Angular code is executed in the context of a *Zone*, encapsulated in a *Module*, and undergoes a *change detection* process.

For this reason a lot of alternative solutions have been developed along with the already existent ones. And there's an Angular "way" of solving some problems, in a range of solutions (e.g. you can manipulate the DOM in a component, but the correct way is with template/ViewChild).

For this reason, here are some good reasons to use injectors in place of global variables:

- You won't pollute the global scope. A global variable will be actually inserted in the `window` object, and in a non-time you will find yourself with thousands of mistery keys
- You have a shared interface to inject values. Just imagine if every third party library had a different solution to make their value available for you, one will create a global variable, one will emit a value, one will use an observable, and so on. It would be a real mess. For the same reason, injection tokens also do avoid conflicts, since the key of the injection token is a shared symbol that you can import in your component.
- Different injector. Indeed, you can require your token everywhere you have an injector, and you can have different injector in your application. You want two components in a microfrontend architecture to communicate? You'll need the same injector.
- Make testing easier. An injection token can make mocking and testing easier. Hardly you can replace a global function instead